# What is an equivalent list comprehension to these nested for loops?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a list of blog titles called `lst` and a list of stop words called `stops`.

This code does exactly what I want, removing every word which appears in both lists from `lst`:

```
for line in lst:
    for stop in stops:
        line = re.sub(r"\b" + stop.rstrip("\n") + r"\b", "", line.lower())
    print(line)
```

However, out of both curiosity and a desire to write more concise/efficient code, I want to turn this into a list comprehension.

I tried this:

```
lst = [[re.sub(r"\b" + stop.rstrip("\n") + r"\b", "", line.lower()) for stop in stops] for line in list]
```

...but to no avail. When executed, the code throws a `ValueError` exception as seen below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Visual Studio Projects\RBTrends\RBTrends\main.py", line 55, in <module> prepData()
  File "F:\Visual Studio Projects\RBTrends\RBTrends\main.py", line 42, in prepData
    filelst = aps.stripStopWords(filelst, STOP_WORDS_PATH)
  File "F:\Visual Studio Projects\RBTrends\RBTrends\articleprocesses.py", line 34, in stripStopWords
    lst = [[re.sub(r"\b" + stop.rstrip("\n") + r"\b", "", line.lower()) for stop in stops] for line in list]
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Could someone please explain the reason for this error, and how I can fix it by writing a different list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code here:

```
lst = [[.... for stop in stops] for line in list]
                                          ----^
```

Replace that `list` with `lst`. `list` is a type name in Python and hence the `ValueError`.

Comment: My bad, I'm tired. Should probably read through the code more thoroughly next time before posting to Stack Overflow...

Comment: @xander Been there. :)

Comment: The original code transforms each line. Your code turns each line into a list of strings of size `len(stops)`.

Comment: @shaktimaan If I wanted to print out the line each time from within the outer loop, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @xander: You'd have to use `reduce` to emulate your inner `for` loop. See my answer.

Comment: @Blender Ah, I see. Using nested for loops is probably an easier solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reproduce your inner loop would be with `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce  # for Python 3

result = [reduce(lambda line, stop: re.sub(r'\b' + stop.rstrip('\n') + r'\b', '', line), stops, line.lower()) for line in lst]
```

Please don't do this. Your code is fine. If you want to speed it up, just pre-compile a regex that replaces all of the words at once.

```
stop_regex = re.compile(r'\b' + r'\b|\b'.join(map(re.escape, stops)) + r'\b')

for line in lst:
    print(stop_regex.sub('', line.lower()))
```